# How to get boolean value from Http Response in Grails

Tags: java, grails, https, http-post, httpresponse

I have kind of a stupid question, but since I can't figure it out I figured I'd post it here to see if anyone can help!

I have some code that makes an `HttpPost` request to our server. I receive the results perfectly in an XML format. The problem is I want to get the boolean value that is returned, not just a String. So for example, a successful call to the web service returns this xml:

```
<boolean xmlns="https://myWebService/">false</boolean>
```

which I can access and read by using this line:

`String responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());`

Is there a way to access the data returned (false, in this case) as a boolean, or will I have to manually parse the return String to get the value?

Thanks for your help

Comment: You need to parse the return String. I don't think it will be direct boolean response.

Answer (score 1):

> will I have to manually parse the return String to get the value?

Yes, but you can simply roll your own method that does the parsing (and etc.) and then returns a `boolean`.

```
public boolean asBoolean(Entity e){
    return Boolean.parseBoolean(EntityUtils.toString(e));
}
```

Comment: It would probably be best to use a response object in the method signature rather than an `Entity`.